# How to find and fix if a jar is using vulnerable version of log4j in windows/linux/mac

Tags: linux, windows, log4j, cve-2021-44228

log4j security vulnerbility find and fix?
Any tool to help find the current usage of log4j version and fix for springboot app.

Comment: See this answer to a related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70363203/17682051

Answer (score 0):

Found this great tool that helped in scanning log4j dependencies used in a jar:
**https://github.com/logpresso/CVE-2021-44228-Scanner**
Install it on the required platform and run the binary with the path to scan. eg: **./log4j2-scan /var/lib/jenkins/**
It'll scan and show you the report.

For the Spring-boot-starter-log4j2 to use the latest version of log4j, follow the below GitHub link and make the required change in the build file to enable spring-boot to make use of the latest required package.

**https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28958**